# Contactable plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm using this plugin [link](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/ajax/contactable-jquery-plugin.html)
 My question is, i want to remove the button (feedback) and instead use a normal link in my html page > < a href="#">Contact< /a> that trigger the plugin 
I deleted this tag from .js file: < div id="contactable_inner">< /div> and now i want to attach my < a> link to the plugin

i don't know jQuery, can anyone help me plz?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change feedback to word contact you can do this see this demo
http://jsfiddle.net/fUeWx/ otherwise if you want to have link as that contact form then i guess you should have to change css accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Hira, but this is not what i meant, i wanted the link to be like this <ul > < li>Home< /li> < li>Contact< /li>< /ul> and in the center of the page </br> i solved it a minute ago and still working on it